# Material UI Slider : I am unable to replace empty space in tool tip and mark label with '\n' in material ui slider

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, slider

I am developing a slider which accepts various data types based on user input. At times when slider supports string data, the tool tips and labels for marks got beyond the margin of slider. I had tried to override the same using class names provided by MUI '.

can someone help me how do I add '\n' where there is space between words. Look below image for your reference. Have tried using replace method to replace empty space with new line, but does not work.

[image]

Have tried using replace method to replace empty space with new line, but does not work. I am able to access MUI classes for accessing the tool tips and mark labels.

Comment: try adding </br> instead of \n in the string

Comment: Using break tag doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.